# How to fetch Object data in react js to show in web page

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Using the Axios and getting this type of data in console  log but when I used this too in the map only on data is showing in a table row and when I refresh the page vale change to 2
I want to store every object in an array of objects by making temp variable and then run in for loop to check the length of the object and store like this:-
temp:[{4 objects}] because it might be more than 4 object

**Code of Axios**

```
 function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    var data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      Postdata([response.data])


    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
```

getting this object may be more than 4 in the future so plz help me

```
{
        "Status": 1000,
        "Properties": {
            "ClipName": "Clip1",
            "Upcounter": "15:33:44:33",
            "DownCounter": "16:33:44:33",
            "ChannelName": "Channel1",
            "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
            "PlayerName": "Vtr1",
            "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
        }
    }
    {
        "Status": 1001,
        "Properties": {
            "ClipName": "",
            "Upcounter": "",
            "DownCounter": "",
            "ChannelName": "",
            "StartTimeCode": "",
            "PlayerName": "",
            "Duration": ""
        }
    }
    {
        "Status": 1000,
        "Properties": {
            "ClipName": "Clip3",
            "Upcounter": "12:33:44:33",
            "DownCounter": "12:33:44:33",
            "ChannelName": "Channel3",
            "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
            "PlayerName": "Vtr3",
            "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
        }
    }
    {
        "Status": 1000,
        "Properties": {
            "ClipName": "Clip4",
            "Upcounter": "19:00:25:776",
            "DownCounter": "19:00:25:776",
            "ChannelName": "Channel4",
            "StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
            "PlayerName": "Vtr4",
            "Duration": "12:00:00:01"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use States in order to map all the data from axios json result to your component. here's an example to render data from axios.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.persons
            .map(person =>
              <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>
            )
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

You need to update your code to introduce states and then render the data in your return statements.

```
 function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    const [data,setData] = useState({});
    var data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setData({response.data});    
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
 return (
      <>
           this.state.data.map( d => <p> {d.Status } </p>);
      </>
 );
```

You can follow up with both functional components and class based components. Read more about Props and Components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)